# How can we add video to a tableview?

Tags: ios

In my app i want to display a video in subsequent rows of a tableview. Video's are to be fetched from a JSON service which is coming in a string format. How can we achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: White more information about what you have tried to solve this issue yourself we will be unable to help you. Please read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: NSString *videoLink=[dict objectForKey:@"Video"];
         NSLog(@"%@",videoLink);
         NSURL *videoURL1 = [[NSURL alloc]init];
         videoURL1 = (NSURL *)videoLink;
         NSLog(@"%@",videoURL1);
         
         MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL1];
         UIImage *imageSel = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
         [player stop];
where video1 is getting a value of this  VMS_1403002649476.mp4

Comment: the dequeue mechanism with tableviewcells will makes your app unreliable

Comment: Actually it is news feed which is to be displayed in a tableview just like facebook @HaneTV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use GET for getting response(VIDEO) from server just you can try in following method

```
 //just give your URL instead of my URL

   NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL              URLWithString:@"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/search.ashx?query=London&num_of_results=3&format=json&key=xkq544hkar4m69qujdgujn7w"]];

  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

  [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

  NSError *err;

  NSURLResponse *response;

  NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&err];

 //You need to check response.Once you get the response copy that and paste in ONLINE  JSON VIEWER.If you do this clearly you can get the correct results.    

 //After that it depends upon the json format whether it is DICTIONARY or ARRAY 

        //If it is Dictionary
   NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
              or
        //If it is Array
   NSMutableArray *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData  options:kNilOptions error:nil];

   NSMutableArray *imgvd=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   for (int i =0 ; i<json.count; i++) 
   {

        NSString *dd =[[json objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSString *pp = [[json objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"title"];
        vedios *myvd = [[vedios alloc]initWithvideo:dd andtitle:pp];
        [imgvd addObject:myvd];
   }
```

Comment: I know how to fetch the video but i need to display it in a table view row using this is MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL1]; UIImage *imageSel = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame]; [player stop];  is giving an error.

Comment: -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";
  vediopoliticalCell *cell = (vediopoliticalCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
     cell= [[vediopoliticalCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];}
   [cell setDataSource:[imgvd objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   NSLog(@"data %@",[imgvd objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
   return cell;
}

Comment: just give your coding in cellForRowAtIndexPath above like that in your  tableview datasource delegate method.